# Handling of accented characters in GMAPSUPP.IMG

Tags: convert, encoding, garmin

I'd like to use my Garmin 20 to go biking. Since I do not want to buy one of microSD card from garmin, I'd like to build one myself.

For this I went to:

- http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/

Selected:

- "Routable Bicycle (Openfietsmap Lite)"

and

- "Enable manual tile selection: "

And then simply selected region north of Toulouse, France:

[image: Toulouse North]

This seems to be the direct link:

- http://osm.pleiades.uni-wuppertal.de/garmin/openfietsmap_lite/07-05-2018/63442359.img

After a couple of minutes, I received an email containing a direct link to the GMAPSUPP.IMG. If I extract this file and copy it:

```
$ unzip openfietsmap_lite_gmapsupp.zip
$ cp gmapsupp.img /media/malat/GARMIN/GARMIN/GMAPSUPP.IMG
```

Then everything works as expected, except one tiny detail: accented characters. My Garmin 20 does not display some city names properly.

Some cities contains odd characters for example:

- Bruguières is stored as "BRUGUI?RES"
- Saint-Geniès-Bellevue is stored as "SAINT-GENI.S-BELLEVUE"
- Villeneuve-lès-Bouloc is stored as "VILLENEUVE-L.S-BOULOC"

Is there a way to export/re-create this particular map using proper Latin1 encoding to fix all the invalid encodings ?

---

Update: I can fix the binary file directly using hexedit, for example I can generate the correct name for "Bruguières" using:

```
$ file input
input: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ cat input
BRUGUIÈRES
$ iconv -o output -f utf8 -t latin1 input
$ file output
output: ISO-8859 text
```

Then I simply replace the original '3F' into 'C8' and then everything works as expected. While this is obviously not a proper solution (I would need to fix hundreds of binary strings) this demonstrate that a proper conversion is possible.

---

It seems the original 'img' file:

- http://osm.pleiades.uni-wuppertal.de/garmin/openfietsmap_lite/07-05-2018/63442359.img

Already contains the invalid character encoding. So I need to generate the img file myself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I need to recreate the map myself. I followed instructions from:

- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin#Directions:_Creating_your_map_from_OSM_data

So this means I went to:

- https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=11/43.7266/1.6261

Because I was getting an error, I followed the advices on the left panel, and went instead to:

- https://overpass-api.de/api/map?bbox=1.2600,43.6259,1.8505,43.8603

I renamed the 'map' file into 'map.osm'. On my Debian system I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mkgmap
$ mkgmap --latin1 --gmapsupp map.osm
```